# Linear set of equations with complex numbers

Tags: linear-algebra, complex-numbers

How can I solve a linear set of equations with complex numbers? I haven't solved a set of equation with complex number before, so I'd like to know if there are particular rules to follow..

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Could you add a little more detail to your question? What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: You can add, subtract, multiply and divide complex numbers, and these operations satisfy the same basic rules (commutativity, associativity, distributivity, etc.) so the algorithms you learned for real numbers should work just as well here.

Comment: @BrettFrankel nothing else? thanks!

Comment: @DoctorBatmanGod I haven't solved a set of equation with complex number before, so I'd like to know if there are  particular rules to follow.. thank you!

Comment: @sunrise: mention this in your question (just append the content of your comment to DoctorBatmanGod to your question).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can solve a linear set of complex equations the same way you would with a linear set of real equations (e.g. substitution methods, Gaussian elimination).